# C# pass date from config file (is it possible)?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, config

Hello currently in my cs file I create a string (to_search_for) in the way I describe below:

```
string date = DateTime.Today.ToString("MMddyy");

string to_search_for = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["part_of_file"] + date + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["file_extension"];
```

Two parts of the string are passed from the config file and one of of it comes from the **current date**: **"*zzrs" + "101513" + ".txt" = "*zzrs101513.txt"**.

After that I use that string to search for a txt file which is generated everyday and the file is named after "*zzrs" and the **current date** and before "zzrs" the letters could be anything.

My question is, is it possible for the date to be generated in the config file instead in the cs file?

Something like:

```
string to_search_for = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["part_of_file"] +
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["date"] +
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["file_extension"];
```

I have searched around and could not find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why you should not be able to pass the date from the config file just as you do with the other strings. All you need to do is put the date you need in the config file, in the format you need to search for (you're not using the date as a Date object anyway - only as a strin!).

If you want the date "automatically generate" as part of the config file, then I guess you would have to create some logic to generate your config file. You could do this, and use different config files for each date you may want to search for, but I can't see why you would want to do that.

I think your existing solution may be the simplest.

As another option, you may consider passing the date as a parameter to you application, if you want to search for other dates than "today".

Comment: Creating another app to generate config files and select different ones makes things more complicates. I agree with you that this is the simplest from, I was just wondering if there is some kind of code to put in the config which will generate date to string in runtime. To enlighten you a bit more, I was thinking that if one day my generated file is named "*rtf.txt" I could remove the date from the config file and replace with and empty string and also change the first part of the file name. If this happens I will need to change the cs file, rebuild the solution and deploy the code. Thanks!